# How to unfreeze Excel 2016 after running VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel

After running macros my main excel functionality are not active...
ie. I can not change color of text and everything is slow,
what else I should switch on/off to revert back to normal operations?
When I close and open everything seems to be correct.
This is text I have at the end of my script. 
I would appreciate your help.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Calculate
```

see image here
[image: unable to change color]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Room_Results_up2_Click()
    Room_Results_up2 (False)

End Sub

Sub Room_Results_up2(ScreenUpdate As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim zonecount As Long

If ScreenUpdate = False Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
End If

Room_ResultsCopy False, False
TempUpdt False, False
TempUpdt2 False, False

Dim zakres As Range
Set zakres = Sheets("Room_Results").Columns("B")
Set zakres = zakres.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
If zakres.CountLarge = 0 Then Exit Sub
Dim kolumna As Long
Dim ileKolumn As Long
Dim komorka As Range
Dim wynik As Variant
ileKolumn = Range("B:CB").Columns.count
Dim f As Range '1

For Each komorka In zakres
    For kolumna = 2 To ileKolumn
        wynik = BezpVLOOKUP(komorka.Value, Sheets("Room_ResultsCopy").Range("B:BZ"), kolumna, False)
        If wynik <> "" Then
            Set f = Sheets("Room_ResultsCopy").Cells.Find(komorka.Value)
            Sheets("Room_ResultsCopy").Cells(f.Row, kolumna + 1).Copy
            Sheets("Room_Results").Cells(komorka.Row, kolumna + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

           Sheets("Room_Results").Cells(komorka.Row, kolumna + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next kolumna
Next komorka

Room_Results_RangeNames.Room_Results_RangeNames

If ScreenUpdate = False Then
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End If

zonecount = Sheets("Room_Results").Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox "Update Done! " & vbNewLine & "Nr of Rows = " & zonecount & vbNewLine & "...by Michal"
Worksheets("Room_Results").Range("D10").Activate



End Sub
```

Comment: That's unusual behavior. We'd need to see the rest of your code to have any chance of telling you whether it's your code which is to blame

Comment: This happened to me some times. Usually I minimize and then maximize my spreadsheet and everything comes back to normal. However, I believe you have too many lines on your code finalization. Try leave the `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and discard the rest. It should do the same thing...

Comment: Where are you putting your code? In `Workbook` - `Open`?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the code that you've supplied, so it's either elsewhere in your code or you have an issue with your installation of office that's unrelated.

Comment: I added full code I already included all this manual, and false ...events.. etc

Comment: I tested leaving only 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic' but it did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Turn screen updating off to speed up your macro code. You won't be able to see what the macro is doing, but it will run faster.
>   Remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx)

As for the text color not changing, I'm not sure why. Maybe it has something to do with `Application.EnableEvents = True`. I read [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37042).